# Interesting Probability Sock Question

Tags: probability

We have been debating the solution to this problem in our math department the last week.  The problem has generated meaningful discussion between teachers and students.  We have two different solutions.   Let us know what you think the answer is.  See below...

Mort has 8 white socks, 6 black socks and 4 gray socks in his drawer, but he
could not tell you that because he pays no attention to such trivial matters. This morning he randomly drew two socks and put them on without noticing their
colors. At school Sally said, “Don’t look now, Mort, but your socks don’t match.
Guess what they are.” Unaware of the numbers involved, Mort rolled a die to
determine his guess (1 or 2 for WB, 3 or 4 for BG, 5 or 6 for GW). Find the
probability that Mort correctly guessed the colors. Give your answer as a reduced common fraction.

Comment: Please include the main sides and their reasoning of the debate you have been having. Otherwise this looks like a thinning veiled attempt to get others to do a students homework.

Comment: I would rather not include the main sides and reasoning just yet.  I don't want to influence any interpretation, and would like to see how others interpret and solve the problem.  I am one of math teachers and this was a math team problem, not a homework problem.

Comment: @Frank To convince the side that is wrong: Put the question on the table again, but now with e.g. only white 8 socks and 6 black socks. Mort rolls and determines his guess: (1,2,3,4,5,6) for WB. What is the probability of guessing correct? $1$ of course. This must be clear for everyone. But those that follow the wrong way in solving this will end up with less than $1$, hence are clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are ${18\choose{2}} = 153$ different ways to choose a pair of socks, but we know from Sally that the socks are mismatched, so there are only 104 ways to choose mismatched pairs. There are $8 \cdot 6$ ways to choose $BW$, $8 \cdot 4$ ways to choose $WG$, and $6 \cdot 4$ ways to choose $BG$. Therefore, we can calculate the probability that Mort randomly grabbed each pair of mismatched socks.

\begin{align*}
P(BW)&= 48/104\\
P(WG)&= 32/104\\
P(BG)&= 24/104\\ 
\end{align*}

Let the event $A$ be defined as the event Mort guess $BW$, the event $B$ be defined as the event Mort guesses $WG$, and the event $C$ the event Mort guess $BG$. The probability that Mort guesses $A$, $B$, or $C$ are equivalent:

$ P(A) = P(B) = P(C) = 1/3 $

There are three events that Mort guess correctly. The event Mort is wearing $BW$ and he guesses $BW$, the event Mort is wearing $WG$ and he guesses $WG$, and the event Mort is wearing $BG$ and he guesses $BG$. Therefore, we want to know the probability that any one of these events will occur:

$P(Correct) = P((A \cap BW) \cup (B \cap WG) \cup (C \cap BG)) = P(A \cap BW) + P(B \cap WG) + P(C \cap BG)$

Note the above is true because the events are mutually disjoint. Calculating the probability of the events are straightforward using the previous information remembering that Mort's guess is independent of the selected socks.

\begin{align*}
P(A \cap BW)&= P(A|BW)*P(BW) = P(A)*P(BW) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{48}{104}\\
P(B \cap WG)&= P(B|WG)*P(WG) = P(B)*P(WG) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{32}{104}\\
P(C \cap BG)&= P(C|BG)*P(BG) = P(C)*P(BG) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{24}{104}\\ 
\end{align*}

Therefore, provided Sally's information we have

$P(Correct | \text{with Sally's information}) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{104}{104} = \frac{1}{3}$.

Edit: Think about the problem this way. Mort is making a random guess from the set of the mismatched possiblities. If Sally does not provide the information that Mort is wearing mismatched socks, then the total number of ways to choose a pair of socks is ${18\choose{2}} = 153$. In this case, Mort would be making a guess from the set of mismatched possiblities, but we do not know that his socks are mismatched, so this would be a worse guess, and we would have a probability, which is worse than $1/3$.

Therefore, if Mort guesses the same way but Sally does not provide any information, we have

$P(Correct | \text{without Sally's information}) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{104}{153} = \frac{104}{459}$.

Comment: And this is the debate we are having in the math department.  Those are the two sides and the reasoning for each.  104/459, what you had the first time, and 1/3.

Comment: Please see my edit for clarification.

Comment: @Frank In the second part leading to $\frac{104}{459}$ cBEiN is showing why the alternate reasoning is false - i.e. we have it from Sally that the socks are unmatched. If you add up all the probabilities for the second argument they will be less than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose he is wearing WB.

Then what is the probability of a correct guess?

And why should that be different if he is wearing another combination?

Comment: I'm still waiting to hear what the other opinion is. That was clearly the way to do it from my point of view.